# Why my firestore rules is not validating writes?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have a collection structure like this.

```
products {
   123456 : {
      stock_qty : (Number)
   }
}
```

I want to validate stock quantity to be positive. I have applied following firebase security rule.

```
 service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read: if request.auth.uid != null;
      allow write: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }
    match /products/{document=**}{
      allow write: if request.resource.data.stock_qty > 0;
    }
  }
}
```

But Still I am able to add products with negative stock_qty.
what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Please edit the question to show the code the performs the update.  We need to be able to see that the your code matches the rules. There should be enough information so that anyone can reproduce the issue.

Comment: Added the complete security rule. Hope this will help.

Comment: How are you building the document in the request? I just tried your rules and they are working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove this part of your rules:

```
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read: if request.auth.uid != null;
      allow write: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }
```

This allows all authenticated users to read and write your entire database, regardless of any other rules you have defined.

If any rule gives access to a document, another rule cannot revoke that access.

If you have other queries for other collections that must be protected, you will need rules for those other collections as well.

Comment: Yes this worked for me although I had to add rules for each collections.. Thank you!!